# Regex that match any string except specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have a case that spend many time for me so i decided to ask here ,

lets say i have a text :

"the time right now is 00:00:11:12"

i want to match any case of time ("xx:xx:xx") except the case of "00:00:00" how can i do this?

Thank from advance :)

Comment: Try `(?!00:00:00)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`.

Comment: `import re
thistime = 'the time right now is 00:00:11:12'
if not re.search("00:00:00", thistime):
    print(thistime)`